# Which class attributes does Pydoc document?

Tags: python, pydoc

I know pydoc can generate documentation for public (not prefixed) methods of a python class. But how can I generate documentation for attributes?

For example, you can see that pydoc creates documentation for 3 methods and 2 attributes:

- `__dict__`
- `__weakref__`

So, my two questions

1. Why does __dict__  have no real information? Wouldn't it have information about class attributes?
2. If all attributes of a python class are in __dict__, then how can I get at documentation for these public attributes?

> ```
> class ImageReader(builtins.object)
>  |  Helper class that provides TensorFlow image coding utilities.
>  |  
>  |  Methods defined here:
>  |  
>  |  __init__(self)
>  |      Create a Reader for reading image information.
>  |  
>  |  decode_image(self, sess, image_data)
>  |      Decode jpeg image.
>  |  
>  |  read_image_dims(self, sess, image_data)
>  |      Read dimension of image.
>  |  
>  |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>  |  Data descriptors defined here:
>  |  
>  |  __dict__
>  |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
>  |  
>  |  __weakref__
>  |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

**What sort of attributes does pydoc document?**

It documents a quirky subset.

```py
    class SomeClass():
        a = "attribute"
        """This is shown"""
    
        def __init__(self):
            self.c = "attribute"
            """This not shown in documentation"""
```

**Why does `__dict__` show no real information?**

"magic" methods are internal implementation details.

pydoc hides a [quirky subset of "magic" or "dunder" methods](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f87ea0350286837e9e96de03f8bfa215176c2928/Lib/pydoc.py#L273). If it doesn't hide one, but the implementing class didn't override the magic method, it shows the uselss documentation.

If it had been overridden, then `__dict__` would show something different.